# Xcode 7 Playground Markup: What is keyboard shortcut for Show Rendered Markup

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7, markup, swift-playground

Since I go back and forth between Raw Markup and Rendered Markup, I wonder there is a keyboard shortcut to move between them.

Answer (score 13):

No, there is none by default but you can easily set it up by going into **Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings**, then search for **markup**:
[image: Screenshot showing Xcode Key Bindings]
The above screenshot shows the assignment of ⌥⇧R.

Comment: if you add key binding for **Show Rendered Markup** it will actually toggle between Rendered and Raw. No need (no ability actually) to also set a key binding for Show Raw Markup